# CentOs won't increase memory limits

Tags: centos, composer-php, cyber-panel

I have VPS using CentOs 7 with CyberPanel and when I try to use `composer install` I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

## Screenshots

[image: one]

[image: two]

Any idea?

Comment: What is the GUI interface in your screenshot? You're probably editing the `php.ini` of another SAPI (ergo not the one for the command-line interface / CLI). PHP uses **multiple** different `php.ini` files dependending on how you start it (i.e. `php-fpm` uses it's own `php.ini`). Make sure to edit the correct one - preferrably with a text editor.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich exactly for that reason i shared screenshots. I edited php7.4 to limit of `5G` and in terminal i showed you my php version is `7.4`

Comment: Please see my answer for instructions how to find the "correct" `php.ini` for the CLI.

Comment: Please share more details - usually, `composer install` does not need that much memory as it won't trigger the dependency resolver. Have you removed `composer.lock` somewhere in the process? Additionally, which version of Composer do you use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solved

I used this command and my composer start to run

```
which composer
```

To find my composer path, and then

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /user/bin/composer update
```

Comment: See my answer for a persistent solution + another option where you can invoke `composer` directory.

Comment: That is not consistent with the question - you've asked about a problem when using `composer install`. An update should not be performed anywhere else than on your development system

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried to use composer install and this command did that for me now if the command in includes update or any other irrelevant words but fix the issue then that's the solution I'm looking for. I don't bind to the words that are in commands but to the results of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Find the correct `php.ini` for your PHP CLI SAPI with the following command:

```sh
php -i | grep 'ini'
```

Add `memory_limit = -1` to this file with a text editor.

You can aswell increase the memory limit for one command with:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

... or ...

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /user/bin/composer update
```

Comment: fixed it with `php -d memory_limit=-1 /user/bin/composer update`